# Generate Models from Rails Schema

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, schema

Is it possible to generate rails models from a rails schema (or migration)?

Comment: I would definatly want to know the answer to this

Comment: I use an database design tool (http://www.malcolmhardie.com/sqleditor/) that will generate a rails schema, it would be great to export from there, run a script and have my models created.

Comment: The [magic_models](https://rubygems.org/gems/magic_models) gem seems to generate models nicely for me. See [github page](https://github.com/rzane/magic_models) for usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you seen this?

[magic_model_generator](https://rubygems.org/gems/magic_model_generator)

Comment: Hasn't been updated for about  6 years or so and not updated to work with Rails 4

Answer (score 4):

Also worth trying is the "Rails-Models-Reverse-Engineering" (rmre) gem: https://github.com/bosko/rmre